# Ignore Parent onClick event when Child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please see - http://www.bootply.com/dR7fxjP1bk

By clicking any of the div.rows (lets call this parent), an onClick event is activated, for demo purposes an alert pops up.

Within the row an accordion collapses when the "info" (orange button) is clicked (lets call this child), but the problem is that the parents alert triggers.

I need the info button not to trigger the alert, only when anywhere else is clicked the alert appears.

I've tried various ways such as using (e)stopPropagation .on .off calls etc... I'm  not the best jquery guy so need a little help getting this to work - and also help me learn something!

```
<div class="row ticket-selector" onclick="alert('Hello World!');">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ticket-panel" href="#collapseOne" class="tickets-more"><span class="halflings info-sign orange"></span></a>
</div>
```

The above is the jist - but see for better understanding - http://www.bootply.com/dR7fxjP1bk

Comment: This is one of the reasons why `onclick=""` is outdated way to handle events...

Comment: Does anybody have a working example of this?

Comment: Take a look at [updated code](http://www.bootply.com/d4Ab9DUkkh).

Comment: Ok thats great, really close with this one... but the onclick needs to stay "inline" as its originally asp.net code - here is an updated bootply - http://www.bootply.com/mm4xEf5kXW I have added jquery that I think should work theoretically from an amateur!

Comment: If you somewhy can't remove old-fashioned `onclick=""` from ASP.NET code, you can turn it off using jQuery like in [this code version](http://www.bootply.com/VkLUBGQhA5).

Comment: I need it to turn off for the info-button only Regent. So when the orange info button is clicked the event does not fire.

Comment: I understood it very well. I suggest to turn off `onclick=""` event handler (as you can see in provided code) and turn on custom event handler (as you can see in provided code).

Comment: Sorry, when I click the orange info btn, I still get "hello world", when I click anywhere else I get "hello world" and "hello real world". When the info button is click all i need to happen is it expands without hello world appearing

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, this damned "bootply.com" doesn't work adequate. Take a look at [once more updated version](http://www.bootply.com/IpoQ2uodCm)

Comment: Ok That works the way it needs to but one thing... can the alert look at the inline onClick rather than resetting the attr (onclick, '') and replacing the alert later on - the reason for this is the asp.net code that I cant take it from the line (i know its old way but that's the deal)

Comment: If all `onclick=""` have same value, you can use [this code](http://www.bootply.com/xc60PmeiXC).

Comment: If all elements have different `onclick` handlers, then you can use [this version](http://www.bootply.com/uKOYz3lqD1).

Comment: That's the one, can you add answer for bounty? Thanks a lot - learned a thing or two as well. I did think to save the data

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, as it's correct one, I'll post it as answer

Comment: I also changed code a little bit: there was unnecessary `$("alert").click`. Final version is in answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to remove `onclick=""` handler saving its value in another field and then to execute (evaluate) value in custom `click` event handler:

[Example code](http://www.bootply.com/BW1spK6lwz).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var elements = $(".ticket-selector");
    elements.each(function()
    {
        var handler = $(this).attr('onclick');
        $(this).data('click', handler);
    });
    elements.attr('onclick', '');
    elements.click(function(e)
    {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass("info-sign"))
        {
            eval($(this).data('click'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Check the working demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/f00d4v54/)

I think you should use **event.stopPropagation()** jquery api and you can use it as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tickets-more').click(function(event){
        // your stuff here
        alert("Alert On Click");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**event.stopPropagation()** stop the event bubbling that you are facing. For further documentation refer the from [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Hope it helps...

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent info block opening: [example](http://www.bootply.com/wy4cYkMtYd).

Answer (score 4):

If the case is avoid clicking on elements inside them, this will help you.

```
function clickhere(obj){
   let theid = obj.id;
   console.log(theid);
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using css classes doesn't bother you, you could check clicked element attributes/classes. Like so:

```
$('.parent-element').on('click',function(e){
if ( $(this).attr('data-toggle') ){//has attribute data-toggle
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
});
```

This will depend on your DOM tree a bit more. You could find a condition that will disable any event

Comment: There is no need in `e.preventDefault();` if you use `return false`, because it includes both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`.  `$(this).attr('data-toggle')` can be simplified into `$(this).data('toggle')`. And once more: `return false` will prevent info block opening.

Answer (score 1):

Use css:

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

This will make the relevant elements completely transparent to mouse events.

Comment: Yeah but he might want to be able to click on those child elements. So he just needs to stopPropagation because you've eventually got to enable those pointer events for any children that need interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

take the info class out of the div. Wrap em both with another clean div.

Answer (score 0):

In the orange button click handler add return false; at the end - this will prevent to bubble the event to the parent. Just like this:

```
jQuery('.tickets-more').click(function(){
    // your stuff here
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false` will prevent info block opening: [example](http://www.bootply.com/R309bFqkyh).

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked for me to trap the click.

```
onclick="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

This can work in many cases, such as for a modal backdrop. It will not fire on the parent if *any* child component is clicked:

```html
<div class="row ticket-selector" onclick="handleClick();">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ticket-panel" href="#collapseOne" class="tickets-more"><span class="halflings info-sign orange"></span></a>
</div>
```

```js
function handleClick(ev) {
  if (ev.target === ev.currentTarget) alert('Hello World!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) function.

> The `stopPropagation()` method of the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed. If you want to stop those behaviors, see the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method. It also does not prevent propagation to other event-handlers of the current element. If you want to stop those, see [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation).
>
> by MDN Docs

```js
const clickToParentElement = (e) => console.log("click to parent")

const clickToElement = (e) => {
  console.log("click to current")
}

const clickToElementWithoutParent = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation() // disable parent events
  clickToElement(e)
}
```

```html
<div onclick="clickToParentElement(event)">
  Click Here (Parent)
  
  <div onclick="clickToElement(event)">
    Click Here (Current)
  </div>
  
  <div onclick="clickToElementWithoutParent(event)">
    Click Here (Current) Without Parent Event
  </div>
</div>
```