# javascript hide div by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the javascript with 2 functions:
1) Show DIV (welcomeDiv) ONCLICK the button;
2) Hide div by clicking on the container DIV (outside of 'welcomeDiv').

```
 function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
        }

 function hideDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "none";
        }
```

Both functions work, but 'welcomeDiv' is hiding even when I click inside it (because, 'welcomeDiv' is the part of the container DIV). So I need to disable hideDiv() function when click happends inside of 'welcomeDiv'.
Something like:
                     `<div id='welcomeDiv' onclick='hideDiv().disable'>`

But I don't know how to write it correctly, tryed many things.
Looking forward, thanks in advance

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061254/ignore-parent-onclick-event-when-child-element-is-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple html file to demo a solution for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container { width: 400px; height: 280px; background-color: #e5e5e5;}
            #welcomeDiv { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #b0b0b0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" onclick="hideDiv();">
            <button onclick="showDiv();">
                Hello
            </button>

            <div id="welcomeDiv">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showDiv() {
                document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "inherit";
                event.stopPropagation();
                // stop propagation on button click event
            }

            function hideDiv() {
                var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
                // filter event handling when the event bubbles
                if (event.currentTarget == target) {
                    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "none";
                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A global `event` object is an IE relict. The standard is that it is passed as argument to the callback `showDiv(event)`. While WebKit/blink base browsers also support the non standart `window.event`, it will fail in FireFox, and probably also in future versions of WebKit/Blink. (@JaniBolkvadze)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
<div id='welcomeDiv' onclick='showDiv()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need access to is the JavaScript 'event' object. This object will contain information about what event has occured, which in this case is a 'MouseEvent'. You can use that data to figure out which element has been clicked by looking at the 'target' property. By giving your containing DIV an ID, we can use that to filter out unwanted clicks:

HTML:

```
<div id="welcomeContainer" onclick="showDiv(event)" style="border: 3px solid red;">
Outer Div
<div onclick="hideDiv(event)" id="welcomeDiv" style="border: 3px solid blue;">Inner Div</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showDiv(event) {
    if(event.target.id === "welcomeContainer"){
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
}

function hideDiv(event) {
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "none";
}
```

Here is a fiddle that shows the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/fmz2h6kj/

Comment: Just as a side note, if you don't want to check for ID values, you could also stop the event from bubbling up to the container by calling 'event.stopPropagation()' at the end of the 'hideDiv()' function. This approach can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmz2h6kj/1/