# CSS-GRID: add a clickable div to layout

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I have these cards that are build using grid-css The problem is I need to make the part of the card highlighted in screenshot clickable, wrapped with  (everything should be clickable apart from 'Separate'). When I try to do it it totally breaks my layout. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
I am new to css-grid and will appreciate an advice.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="row">Row 1</div>
    <div class="info bottom-row">
      <div class="info-inner">
        <span> Info</span> <span> Separate</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color bottom-row"></div>
    <div class="row">Row 1</div>
    <div class="info bottom-row">
      <div class="info-inner">
        <span> Info</span> <span> Separate</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5px repeat(3, auto) auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.color {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  background: purple !important;
}

.row {
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-column: 2/-2;
}

.info {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  display: flex;
}

.info-inner {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.cell {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.bottom-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  display: contents;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper:last-child > * {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a class for you span that you want seperate, then use the :not function to disregard it from being selected and tell the cursor to be initial.

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5px repeat(3, auto) auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.color {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  background: purple !important;
}

.row {
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-column: 2/-2;
}

.info {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  display: flex;
}

.info-inner {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.seperate:not(.wrapper) {
    cursor: initial;
}

.cell {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.bottom-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  
}

.wrapper {
  display: contents;  
  cursor: pointer;

}

.wrapper:last-child > * {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="row">Row 1</div>
    <div class="info bottom-row">
      <div class="info-inner">
        <span> Info</span> <span class="seperate"> Separate</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color bottom-row"></div>
    <div class="row">Row 1</div>
    <div class="info bottom-row">
      <div class="info-inner">
        <span> Info</span> <span class="seperate"> Separate</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell bottom-row">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's cool! But I really need it to be a separate thing, 'Separete' will be a button, once you click on it something will happen. And if you click on card - another thing will happen.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand why it wont work for you. You can easily make it a button and do whatever you need to to it, see here https://jsfiddle.net/2L3mqsbj/ Maybe I'm just not understanding the question.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-water-vhkfw?file=/index.html basicly if I click "seperate" I want to see only one alert, not 2 like now...

Comment: because if you click separate 2 things will run: one for   separate, another for card https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-water-vhkfw?file=/index.html

Comment: Understood, I'll take another look into it.

Comment: thank you! btw i can not use something like  event prevent propagation because the Card is actually a Router link from npm dependency  so there is just no place to place this code.

Comment: Might not be the best approach, but I got it working.  Would this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/5k79Lz4v/  I changed your onclick function from the main wrapper to only the individual cell classes and made a different one for the separate section.

Comment: yeah, that's what I am trying to avoid... adding it to everything one by one.

Comment: Yeah I figured,  I'm pretty tapped on ideas for CSS besides rewriting it all.  You might need to do this in JS.  I found this link here which might give some insight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061254/ignore-parent-onclick-event-when-child-element-is-clicked

Comment: thank you, but it uses e.stopPropagation(), and I can not apply it (